# Teamcity not showing NuGet Feed

Tags: teamcity

I am a newbie to TeamCity.
I have installed TeamCity.
However, NuGet Feed is not appearing in the TeamCity Administration page under Integration.
I have also installed Nuget.
Please help me understand what I am missing.

[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently. What sorted it for me was updating TeamCity to the latest version (2019.1 build 65998 for me)

Answer (score 1):

That is a change since 2018.2 or previous versions 2018.1.
Nuget Feeds are in

> Project settings -> NuGet Feed -> Add new NuGet Feed

[Nuget Feed not showing in 2018.2](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002836440-Nuget-Feed-not-showing-in-2018-2)